# Intercept and modify JSON string before jQuery.getJSON() does its thing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use jQuery's `getJSON` call to rerieve the content from a file called `my.json`.

Now sometimes the JSON file contains a certain character, that would invalidate the syntax. Unfortunately, it is not in my power to change that.

I thought it would be easy to use the `success` thing to intercept the JSON string and dix it, before $.getJSON() reads it and fails because the syntax is invalid. Obviously, it's not as easy, as I thought.

I would appreciate, if someone could help me out fixing below code.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        if (xhr.overrideMimeType) {
            xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json");
        }},
    cache: false
});

$.getJSON("my.json", function(data){
    // Do something with the JSON
    console.log("JSON object: " + data);
}).success(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // Intercept JSON string and modify it.
    var fixed_json = fix_json(jqXHR.responseText);
    jqXHR.responseText = fixed_json; // Obviously not as simple as I thought.
});
```

Comment: Use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com) and then "fix" and parse the data in the `success` handler

Comment: why not use `.ajax()` and change the `dataType` of the call if you dont know if its going to be valid json or not and then process it in your success/done function.

Comment: `$.ajax` won't help if the server tries to be clever and sets the `Content-Type: application/json` response header, a.k.a it commits a protocol violation. In this case jQuery will also attempt to parse the server response before handling it to the `success` callback. In this case maybe `dataType: 'text'` could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `success` callback of `$.ajax()` to do the required check on the returned data. It would require you to set the `dataType` to `text` though, so that jQuery doesn't try and automatically parse it for you. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "my.json", 
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
        var obj;
        try {
            obj = JSON.parse(data);
        } 
        catch(e) {
            obj = fix_json(data);
        }

        // work with the object here...
    })
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/no9je7bu/)

Depending on the work that `fix_json` does, and assuming that it always returns an object, you could call that directly and remove the try/catch.